# Firestore onSnapshot rules throw error when deleting document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm having an issue with a Firestore observer and it's associated rules. I'm trying to have rules that only allow the user to see invites that contain the user's email address. However, if I delete a document from the collection, the snapshot observer throws an error `Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: Null value error. for 'get' @ L92`.

Here's my rules:

```
 match /invites/{inviteID} {

      function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
      }

      function isUserInvite() {
        return request.auth.token.email != null &&
        request.auth.token.email == resource.data.user_email;
      }

      allow read: if isSignedIn() && isUserInvite();
      allow write: if true;

}
```

And here's my listener.

```
firebase.firestore()
.collection("invites")
.where(`user_email`, '==', myUserEmail) // this would be the users email
.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {

  snapshot.forEach( doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, doc.data())
  })

})
```

It works for observing new documents, but fails when deleting a document. The following code makes the observer throw an error.

```
// creates a new invite and the snapshot listener informs me 
await firebase.firestore()
.collection('invites')
.doc("invite_1")
.set({
  user_email: someUserEmail, // use the users email here 
  date_added: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})

// deletes the invite, but the snapshot throws an error
await firebase.firestore()
.doc(`invites/invite_1`)
.delete()
```

**UPDATE**

I've found that this is only happening in the firestore emulator and not in production. Both the emulator and production have the same rules.

Comment: Could  you edit the question to be more specific about what you're doing?  In particular, you should say *which* document you're deleting, and what you expect to happen instead with the snapshot listener.

Comment: Hey there. Updated the question. I don't expect the listener to throw an error and stop working (which is what it's currently doing). I would think listener should just return a new set of results without the deleted document.

Comment: It would be nice if things were more specific.  There are a lot of variables in play here, and documents we can't see.  We should be able to reproduce the issue on our own given what you provide in the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson Updated again. Sorry if there wasn't enough clarity at first. Turns out the issue is only happening when using the emulator. I'm going to keep digging and see if I can find why that's the case.

Comment: If it's only with the emulator, then it might be a bug, and you should file it here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @JoeBayLD did you file a bug for this? I searched the repo Doug linked and didn't see a matching bug report.

Comment: @JoshLyon I did. Just answered my own question on here. Google has fixed the bug! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After submitting a bug report to Google - they confirmed it was a bug that only applied to the emulator. This was fixed in a new release. Here’s a link to the GitHub issue for any needed reference.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2197